# Matlab script with version dependent command

Tags: c#, matlab, com

I've developed a plugin for Matlab using the COM API with late binding in C#. 
It works for all versions from 2009bSP1 and forward.

However Matlab recently released the 2012b Prerelease which breaks the functionality. I've updated all the C# code to work. The thing that breaks functionality is that Mathworks changed the structure of callbackInfo items. Before it was possible to call:

```
var = callbackInfo.Model.Name
```

In 2012b Prerelease they have changed it to

```
var = callbackInfo.model.Name
```

Note the lower case "m" in model.

Is there some way for me to decide which one of these to call depending on the version of matlab the script is invoked from?

Best Regards

Robin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[verLessThan](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/verlessthan.html) allows you to check if the version of a matlab toolbox is older than a user specified string:

```
if verLessThan('matlab', '7.15') % if earlier release than 7.15
    % your code
end
```

Comment: Greatly appreciated! I will try this but sounds like exactly what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Matlab functions `version` and `ver` to get the information you need at run time and branch accordingly. `verLessThan` might also be of use to you.

Comment: Is it possible to call "version -release" in a script? In that case how? Otherwise I guess it is necessary to substring in some smart way to get the only the release name.

Comment: @RobinRye you can use `version('-release')` or of course `verLessThan` which is intended for these kind of things